# Datatool : can't use \DTLreplaceentryforrow in nested loop "foreach"

Tags: datatool

In the following MWE (which make no real sense, but which is minimal:) ) I have two nested `DTLforeach` loops. The values displayed in the line "`%for debugging`" show the expected behaviour for the `DTLforeach` loops: the first loop runs on all entries (4 rows). For each of these rows, the second loop runs on rows. But the command `\DTLreplaceentryforrow{a}{xx}`, which should replace the value of `a` by "`xx`", does not do it. Notice, that if you move `\DTLreplaceentryforrow{a}{xx}` outside from the inner loop, then it works as expected. Thus, there seems to be a problem with this command in a nested loop. (REM: according to datatools-documentation, `DTLforeach` can be nested up to three times.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{table}
\DTLrowcount{table}

\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{1}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{oui}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{2}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{oui}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{1}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{non}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{a}{2}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{b}{non}

\section{original table}

\DTLdisplaydb{table}

\section{modified table}

\DTLforeach{table}{\a=a,\b=b}{%
\DTLforeach{table}{\aa=a,\bb=b}{%
a= \a , b= \b , aa=\aa , bb=\bb % only for debugging

\DTLreplaceentryforrow{a}{xx}
}
}

\DTLdisplaydb{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem probably arises due to internal handling of the replacement and grouping of loops.
If your outer loop is never in a write position (will never change the contents of the table.) you can use the starred version, which is read only and will not save the state of the table.

I.e.

```
\DTLforeach*{table}{\a=a,\b=b}{%
    \DTLforeach{table}{\aa=a,\bb=b}{%
        a= \a , b= \b , aa=\aa , bb=\bb % only for debugging
        \DTLreplaceentryforrow{a}{xx}
    }
}
```

this will produce what you want. I guess it is a security of the table loop, to not be able to double foreach of the same table. 
I suggest the above strategy.
However if you wish to change in both loops other methods has to be employed. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but at least an explanation from Nicola Talbot (author of `datatool`):

The contents of a database are stored in a single token register (`toks`) with markers 
indicating rows and cells. When the database is edited, the contents of the token
are split into three parts: the part that needs replacing, everything that comes
before and everything that comes after. The updated database is then formed from merging
the before part, the replacement and the after part. To improve efficiency, the
`\DTLforeach` loop makes a copy of the current row and manipulates just the row copy
rather than the entire database. At the end of the iteration, the current row in the
database is replaced with the copy. In the nested loop in the example, when both 
loops are editing the same row of the database, there are two copies of that
row, one being manipulated by the outer loop, the other by the inner loop. At the
end of the inner loop, the database is updated with the inner copy, but when the
outer loop reaches the end of its iteration, it substitutes its row, which overwrites
the effect of the inner loop.

Comment: very instructive.