# \DTLdeletedb (from datatool package) has no effect within \foreach

Tags: loops, foreach, datatool

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool)

`\DTLgdeletedb` is available in (v2.13) and later.

---

I am trying to use a `\foreach` loop to iterate over a few items. For each iteration of the steps of `\ExtractData`  are:

1. Load the data into `mydb`.
2. Extract the appropriate data.
3. Delete `mydb`.

This works just fine outside of a `\foreach`. But if used within a `\foreach`, it appears that the database is not deleted, and any subsequent attempt to create a new database with the same name fails with:

> Package `datatool` Error: Database `myDB' already exists.

### Notes:

- The MWE example below, shows that that database access is working fine outside of a `\foreach`, and within the very *first* invocation within a `\foreach`.
- The failure occurs **only** if an attempt is made to use `\ExtractData` after  a use within the `\foreach`.  So uncommenting any of the commented blocks will show the failure.
- Before someone asks why I close and re-open the same db, in my actual usage, the data file opened is different for each member of the `\foreach`.  Just the name of the data base is the same. I guess I could create a new name each time, but I'd really like to know what the actual problem is.

### Reference:

- This question about [Datatool : can't use \DTLreplaceentryforrow in nested loop “foreach”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42006/datatool-cant-use-dtlreplaceentryforrow-in-nested-loop-foreach) seems somewhat related but since I am not using a `\DTLforeach` to iterate thru the database, I don't think it helps me.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
    Smith, John, 1977-05-04
    Doe,   Jane, 1980-05-04
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\ExtractData}[3]{% #1=file name #2=row, #3=col
    \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={LastName, FirstName, DOB}]{myDB}{#1}%
    \IfEq{\DTLrowcount{myDB}}{0}{%
        \def\Value{NO VALUE}
    }{%
        \DTLgetvalue{\Value}{myDB}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
    \DTLdeletedb{myDB}%
    \Value%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Works}
\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{2}
\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{1}

\section{Works in foreach (one element)}
\foreach \x in {2}{
    \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\x}
}

\section{Does NOT work subsequent to foreach (one element)}

%\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{1}

%\foreach \x in {1}{
%   \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\x}
%}

\section{Does NOT works in foreach (more than one element)}
%\foreach \x in {2,1}{
%   \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\x}\par\noindent
%}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the usual problem: `\foreach` works in a group, so the `\DTLdeletedb` inside the `\foreach` deletes the database only locally.

Comment: @egreg: I did think of that but since `\DTLloaddb` and `\DTLdeletedb` were within the same scope I though they would either both load/delete locally or both load/delete globally so did not think that that was the problem.

Comment: AFAIK, each step of `\foreach` is run in a distinct group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\foreach` works inside a group, so the deletion of the database is only local. Define a "global" deletion command `\DTLgdeletedb` and use that.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DTLgdeletedb}[1]{%
  \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
  {%
    \dtlforeachkey(\@dtl@key,\@dtl@col,\@dtl@type,\@dtl@head)\in{#1}\do
    {%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname dtl@ci@#1@\@dtl@key\endcsname\undefined
    }%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtldb@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlkeys@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlrows@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlcols@#1\endcsname\undefined
  }%
  {%
    \PackageError{Can't delete database `#1':
       database doesn't exist}{}{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

It's just the same as the `\DTLdeletedb` command, but with `\global` prepended. I'm afraid that heavy use of this approach can pollute the save stack; be warned.

Comment: I'll add this (and a global version of `\DTLcleardb`) to the next version of datatool. (You can track the progress of this feature using my [feature tracker](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/featuretracker.cgi?action=view&key=5).)

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer this question but I want to mention that the loop `\@for` works well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
    Smith, John, 1977-05-04
    Doe,   Jane, 1980-05-04
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\ExtractData}[3]{% #1=file name #2=row, #3=col
    \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={LastName, FirstName, DOB}]{myDB}{#1}%
    \IfEq{\DTLrowcount{myDB}}{0}{%
        \def\Value{NO VALUE}
    }{%
        \DTLgetvalue{\Value}{myDB}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
    \DTLdeletedb{myDB}%
    \Value%
}
\makeatletter
\let\myloop\@for
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Works}
\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{2}
\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{1}

\section{Works in foreach (one element)}

\myloop\xx:={2}\do{%
  \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\xx}%
  }

\section{Does NOT work subsequent to foreach (one element)}

\ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{1}

\myloop\xx:={1}\do{%
   \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\xx}%
}

\section{Does NOT works in foreach (more than one element)}
\myloop\xx:={2,1}\do{%
   \ExtractData{foo.dat}{1}{\xx}\par\noindent%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Will keep the `@for` loop in mind next time I get into trouble with a `\foreach`, which I am sure will happen. :-)