# Spurious blank space when loading a datatool database

Tags: spacing, datatool, database

I am getting spurious blank spaces inserted upon loading a `dtltool` db.

The MWE below produces links to all the image files named with a prefix the same as the .tex file:

[image]

But if I comment out the `\DTLloaddb` line (as indicated by the comments in the code), this produces:

[image]

Note that the indentation increases as the number of files being linked to increases.  Even with zero matches (as is the case for the `A.tex` file), there is still an indentation.

I suspect that this is related to an earlier problem of mine where I was seeing a [Spurious blank space when adding a member to a database within \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70031/spurious-blank-space-when-adding-a-member-to-a-database-within-foreach). I tried to use added an `\unskip` whenever I invoke `\AddMemberToDB`, but that does not help in this case.

### Bonus Question:

- This is not really TeX related, but how do I change the invocation of `ls` such that the error messages such as the following are not displayed in the console.

  > ls: B-*.pdf: No such file or directory

  I had this working with a discussion in the chat room, but started to break in my real use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% -------------------------------------- Create the necessary files
%% Four .tex files:
\begin{filecontents*}{A.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{B.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{C.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{D.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

% No .png file associated with A

% One image file associated with B
\begin{filecontents*}{B-1.png}
\end{filecontents*}

% Two image files associated with C
\begin{filecontents*}{C-1.png}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{C-2.jpg}
\end{filecontents*}

% Three image files associated with D
\begin{filecontents*}{D-1.png}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{D-2.png}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{D-3.jpg}
\end{filecontents*}
%% -------------------------------------- 


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51854/dtldeletedb-from-datatool-package-has-no-effect-within-foreach
%
%  Usage: Use \DTLgdeletedb instead of \DTLdeletedb
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DTLgdeletedb}[1]{%
  \DTLifdbexists{#1}{%
    \dtlforeachkey(\@dtl@key,\@dtl@col,\@dtl@type,\@dtl@head)\in{#1}\do
    {%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname dtl@ci@#1@\@dtl@key\endcsname\undefined
    }%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtldb@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlkeys@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlrows@#1\endcsname\undefined
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dtlcols@#1\endcsname\undefined
  }{%
    \PackageError{***** Error: Can't delete database `#1':
       database doesn't exist}{}{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother



\newcommand{\AddLinkToFile}[3][black]{%
    %#1 = text color
    %#2 = file to open upon clicking
    %#3 = text to display
    %
    \href{run:#2}{\protect\textcolor{#1}{#3}}%
}%


\newcommand{\ListAllAssociatedImageFilesOfTypeInCSV}[3][\jobname.ImageDB]{%
    % #1 = temp file name
    % #2 = dir        
    % #3 = file extension
    \immediate\write18{%
        ls -1 #2#3 %
        | grep -v "No such file or directory" %
        | sort -f%
%       >&2 % List ALL files
        > ./#1% Store in given file name 
    }%
}%


\newcounter{NumRowElements}
\newcommand*{\NumberOfElementsBeforeLinebreak}{2}
\newcommand*{\ListOfImageFileTypes}{jpg,png,pdf}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{NumRowElements}{0}%
    \par\noindent%
    \foreach \x in {A,...,D}{%
        \DTLifdbexists{ImageDB}{\DTLgdeletedb{ImageDB}}{}%
        \ListAllAssociatedImageFilesOfTypeInCSV[\jobname.ImageDB]
                {\x}{-*.{\ListOfImageFileTypes}}%
        % If comment out the following \DTLloaddb, the no additional indentation
        \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={FileName}]{ImageDB}{\jobname.ImageDB}%
        %------------------------------------------------------------
        \makebox[4.0cm][l]{%
            \AddLinkToFile[red]{\x.tex}{\x}%
            \hspace*{1.0ex}%
            \DTLifdbexists{ImageDB}{%
                \DTLifdbempty{ImageDB}{%
                    % no associated image files found.
                }{%
                    \DTLforeach{ImageDB}{\ImageFile=FileName}{%
                        \hspace*{1.0ex}%
                        \AddLinkToFile[gray]{\ImageFile}{\ImageFile}%
                    }%
                }%
            }{}%
        }%
        % Add a new line if we are at the appropriate multiple
        \stepcounter{NumRowElements}%
        \IfEq{\arabic{NumRowElements}}{\NumberOfElementsBeforeLinebreak}{%
            \setcounter{NumRowElements}{0}%
            \par\noindent%
        }{}%
    }%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to comment out an EOL character in `\@dtl@readline`. I'll get it fixed in the next version of `datatool`.

Comment: This problem has been fixed in `2013/01/15 v2.13` version of `datatool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 2.30 (2018-04-16).

Patch for v2.29:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\@dtl@construct@lopoff#1#2{%
  \noexpand\long
    \noexpand\def\noexpand\@dtl@lopoff#1##1##2\noexpand\to##3##4{%
      \noexpand\ifx#2##1\noexpand\relax
        \noexpand\ifstrempty{##1}%
        {\noexpand\@dtl@qlopoff#1{}##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}%
        {%
          \noexpand\dtl@ifsingle{##1}%
          {\noexpand\@dtl@qlopoff#1##1##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}%
          {\noexpand\@dtl@qlopoff#1{##1}##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}%
        }%
      \noexpand\else
        \noexpand\ifstrempty{##1}%
        {\noexpand\@dtl@lop@ff#1{}##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}%
        {%
          \noexpand\dtl@ifsingle{##1}%
          {\noexpand\@dtl@lop@ff#1##1##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}% <---
          {\noexpand\@dtl@lop@ff#1{##1}##2\noexpand\to##3##4\relax}% <---
        }%
      \noexpand\fi
  }%
}%
\DTLsetseparator{,}%
\makeatother
```

Patch for earlier versions (don't use this with v2.29 as that changed some of the internals, including `\@dtl@readline`, in order to fix another problem):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dtl@readline}[2]{%
  \read#1 to #2%
  \ifdefempty{#2}%
  {%
  }%
  {%
    \dtl@trim#2%
  }% <- added comment character
}
\makeatother
```

(You can track the progress of the bug with [my bug tracker](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=9).)

Comment: So, this is different than the problem discovered in [Spurious blank space when adding a member to a database within \foreach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70031/spurious-blank-space-when-adding-a-member-to-a-database-within-foreach).  It seems that `\let\Old@dtl@updatekeys\@dtl@updatekeys
\renewcommand*{\@dtl@updatekeys}[3]{\Old@dtl@updatekeys{#1}{#2}{#3}\unskip}` also works so thought that perhaps that was related.

Comment: @PeterGrill It's a different problem but the same basic cause (a missing percent character at the end of a line). The problem with `\@dtl@updatekeys` was fixed in v2.11, so Werner's patch in your link is no longer required. (I tried neatening up the code in datatool.sty to make it easier to read, but I think I must've missed commenting some EOL characters. Hopefully that's the last one!)

Comment: Nicola: It seems as if this bug is back. I can reproduce this exact issue with the above MWE (after commenting out the `\newcommand*{\DTLgdeletedb}`).  The `\DTLloaddb` is inserting the spurious space (as commeting out that line does not result in any space). I am working on a simpler test case for a new question but until I make one I thought I'd let you know in case this is a known issue.  Using `listfiles` I have the version I am using is `datatool.sty    2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)`, `datatool-base.sty    2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)` and `datatool-fp.sty    2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)`.

Comment: I just clicked through onto your web site and the test case you use reproduces the problem: [Bug Tracker](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=All&status=All&search_string=&key=9). Let me know if I should post a new question.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for letting me know. A bug fix in v2.29 has changed the internals. I'll have a look to see what's causing it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Now fixed in v2.30 (hopefully for good this time!)