# Macro shifts to the right

Tags: tikz-pgf

Every time I'm using this macro it shifts to the right. Why?

```
\newcommand*{\addLine}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \coordinate (x) at (#1,0);
        \draw [open triangle 45-] (0,0) -- (x);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

**Edit**

Well, I adapted my real macro (I just provided a smaller example for the sake of demonstration), but I still have a little gap:

```
    \newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
                \coordinate (x) at (#2,0);
                \coordinate (a) at ($(x)!(#1.north)!($(x)+(0,1)$)$);
                \coordinate (b) at ($(a)+(0.5,0)$);
                \coordinate (c) at ($(b)+(0,#3)$);
                \draw [open triangle 45-] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
                \node[right] at (c) {\bf\sffamily\smaller#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
```

Comment: Try `\newcommand*{addLine}[1]{%` and `\end{tikzpicture}%`.  I'm not sure what packages are required to get your example to compile, so I can't test.  Possibly also a `%` after `remember picture]%`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your macro is introducing spurious spaces.  See [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions)

With comment chars:

[image]

Without comment chars:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand*{\addLine}[1]{% <--- a space is introduced without this %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \coordinate (x) at (#1,0);
        \draw [open triangle 45-] (0,0) -- (x);
    \end{tikzpicture}% <--- a space is introduced without this %
}
\begin{document}
\addLine{1}\addLine{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always wondered what's the matter of this :D

Comment: Now you know!  They're easy enough to miss, see for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86265/14100

Comment: Hi Scott: I think there's another problem. Please have a look on my edits.

Comment: I'm super-flashed: I put a `%` to the end of the macro usage. Now the gap is gone... Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are having the same issue in document.